# Два постпозитивных номинатива?

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

> Начали украинские сериалы в России показывать. Молодцы, правильное решение!

Молодцы и правильное решение - это два разных постпозитивных номинатива? Может ли один постпозитивный номинатив следовать за другим? Или это разные конструкции?

Comment: Ничего плохого в этой фразе нет.

Comment: Спасибо, я согласен с Вами. Вопрос больше о синтаксическом статусе этих конструкций. Это постпозитивные номинативы или нет?